# Не получается проверить столкновение объектов в Unity 2D

Tags: unity3d

Делаю 2д игру в которой есть игрок (ракета которая стреляет) и враги (пришельцы которые летят вниз).

Мне нужно проверить столкновение пули с врагом, но у меня никак не получается это сделать.

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.layer == LayerMask.NameToLayer("Laser"))
        {
            this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

это код в скрипте врага

Ниже инспектор пули.

[image: inspector]

Comment: Приведите больше информации насчет пули. Будет хорошо если вы приведете скрин инспектора пули.

Comment: @nchistov, показал

Answer (score 0):

В чём проблема, раз уж на пуле есть коллайдер, сделать проверку не по слою объекта, а по его тегу:

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Laser"))
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Только не забудь пуле добавить тег `Laser`

Comment: Вообще не работает, пули просто насквозь пролетают. Тег добавил, название совпадает с проверяемым. У врага есть коллайдер.

Comment: помимо коллайдера хотя бы на одном из объектов должен быть rigidbody

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский, благодарю вас!